# should i allocate memory inside a function or place function has been called

Tags: c, function, malloc

Let's suppose I am passing a pointer to an array or a structure to a function.

Like

```
myfun1(struct node *head, int* arr, int N){
    head = malloc(sizeof head);
    arr = malloc(N* sizeof arr);
    ......
}
myfun2(struct node *head, int* arr){
 ...
}
```

And I am calling these functions from another function

```
void CallingFunction(void){
    struct node* head1 = NULL;
    int *arr1;

    struct node* head2 = NULL;
    int *arr2;

    int N = 10;

    head2 = malloc(sizeof head);
    arr2 = malloc(N* sizeof arr);

    myfunc1(head1, arr1, N);
    myfunc2(head2, arr2);
 }
```

Which method of calling a function is better. `myfun1` or `myfun2` ?

Should I allocate memory to structure and array from CallingFunction or inside function ?

EDIT:

As pointed out, program has some mistakes, let's say I correct these two mistakes.

```
  head = malloc(sizeof *head);
  myfunc2(head2, arr2, N);
```

Now, what would be the answer. should  I allocation memory inside callingFunction() or myfun().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a memory leak (besides the wrong `sizeof head` and `sizeof arr`). You have to pass `struct node **` to set the function parameters.

The second is better (besides not getting the size of `arr`) : It does not hide memory allocation and leads to proper pairing of malloc/free inside the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

```
head = malloc(sizeof head);
```

is wrong, you want to reserve space with the size of an object, not with the size of a pointer to this object, change to:

```
head = malloc(sizeof *head);
```

> Which method of calling a function is better. myfun1 or myfun2 ?

You can not reserve space for an array without knowing how many elements, `myfun2` doesn't works.

Comment: mybad, lets say i correct the mistake head = malloc(sizeof *head); and I am passing N in myfunc2 . Then  which one would be better ?

Comment: I don't get you, if you pass `N` to `myfun2` both functions are equal, isn't it?

Comment: for myfun1() I am allocating memory in myfun1() and for myfun2(), I am allocating memory in callingFunction().

Comment: Do you mean if it is better to divide code in two calls instead of use a big function to do all the task? Then yes, divide.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are correct and choosing the best option depends on what the lifecycle of the allocated block will be; it's important to pair memory allocation and release operations. If that memory is only going to be used inside the `myfun1()/myfun2()` context, I would recommend allocating and releasing it there. However, if it will persist and be used in other parts of the program, it would be better to make it very obvious where memory is allocated and released rather than have it be a side effect of some other operation.

Also, I would recommend always using `sizeof(struct node)` and `sizeof(int)` instead of `sizeof(*head)` and `sizeof(*arr)`. It's much clearer and prevents the kind of mistakes others have pointed out in your original code.

In the context of `myfun1()`, `sizeof(head)` gives you the size of a *pointer to a struct* whereas `sizeof(*head)` gives you the size of the *struct itself*, which is what you want in this case.

Likewise, `sizeof(arr)` gives you the size of a *pointer to an int* and `sizeof(*arr)` gives you the size of a *single int*.

Using the sizeof operand with arrays has yet another caveat: its behaviour depends on the context in which the array was declared and whether it's allocated on the stack or on the heap.

Here's a small program that exemplifies this. Pay particular attention to `sizeof(stackArray)` when used within the same context in which the array was declared.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

void aux(int *stackArray, int *heapArray) {
    printf("\nIn a different context:\n");
    printf("sizeof(*stackArray) == sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(*stackArray));
    printf("sizeof(*heapArray) == sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(*heapArray));
    printf("sizeof(stackArray) == sizeof(int *): %zu\n", sizeof(stackArray));
    printf("sizeof(heapArray) == sizeof(int *): %zu\n", sizeof(heapArray));
}

int main() {
    int stackArray[N];
    int *heapArray = malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    printf("In the context in which they were declared/allocated:\n");
    printf("sizeof(*stackArray) == sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(*stackArray));
    printf("sizeof(*heapArray) == sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(*heapArray));
    printf("sizeof(stackArray) == N * sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(stackArray));
    printf("sizeof(heapArray) == sizeof(int *): %zu\n", sizeof(heapArray));

    aux(stackArray, heapArray);

    free(heapArray);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that program in my machine is:

> In the context in which they were declared/allocated:
>   sizeof(*stackArray) == sizeof(int): 4
>   sizeof(*heapArray) == sizeof(int): 4
>   sizeof(stackArray) == **N * sizeof(int)**: 40
>   sizeof(heapArray) == sizeof(int *): 8
>
> In a different context:
>   sizeof(*stackArray) == sizeof(int): 4
>   sizeof(*heapArray) == sizeof(int): 4
>   sizeof(stackArray) == sizeof(int *): 8
>   sizeof(heapArray) == sizeof(int *): 8

In short, if you always use `sizeof()` with the types you want instead of variable names, you don't need to worry about these things.

Answer (score 0):

```
 arr2 = malloc(N* sizeof arr);
```

I recommend to use calloc instead of doing a multiplication inside malloc argument:

Example:

```
 arr2 = calloc(N, sizeof(*arr));
```

Normally myfunc2 is preferred unless  the function is a wrapper to allocate something, in which case another function to deallocate memory exist.